# Checkout back to master from branch and failed to make commit on master

Tags: git, github

1. I created a new branch, Branch A
2. I made changes on Branch A and committed, branch A is a few commits ahead of the master branch
3. I used 'git checkout master' to get back to the master branch
4. I made some changes in one of the files
5. I tried to use 'git status', but it cannot see the changes I made, therefore cannot add or commit the changes

```
What I want to do:
from:
1 - 2  (master)
      \ 
       6 - 7 (Branch A)

to:
1 - 2 - 3 (master)
      \ 
       6 - 7 (Branch A)
```

not merging or anything complicated

Comment: Your process is fine, there's something odd here, your new changes (after checkout master) should appear in git status output. Maybe double-check your steps (modifications and status)

Comment: Another explanation is that the files you changed on master are ignored by Git. What files are you changing on the master branch, and what (if anything) is in your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: To check if it's ignored: [`git check-ignore -v -- path/to/file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore).

Answer (score 0):

you can't see the changes of other branches. If you wanna check other branch commit you have to checkout the branch to see the commit.

if you wanna see the changes that you made on the branch you can run `git diff` . then you can see what actually differ from previous one. If you wanna make same commit to your all branch then you have to merge commit.